# How is the migration shortlist defined?

Tags: support, migration

Now that we graduated to a full site, we can unlock [migration paths to other sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/). Remember that moderators can always do arbitrary site-to-site migrations, but regular users can close and vote to migrate questions when they have over 3000 reputation.

The shortlist has a maximum of 5 sites, and one of them is this meta site. How are the other four sites chosen? Do we vote for them?

*Original question, no longer valid after Jeff's answer:*

This leaves us four other places we can choose (unless [my proposal to add tag-based migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags) is accepted). I suggest you add one site per answer, and we see which sites get the most votes (this can be Community Wiki, but reputation doesn't matter on this meta site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't done through voting -- it is done through history of actual questions being closed.

If you want to prove that your site needs a particular migration path, first point to a lot of closed and/or migrated questions that provide *evidence* for this path.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood how it was done on other sites. I'll update the question and accept this answer.